# OR-Tools: VRPTW with resource constraints and without solution

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing

I'm trying to test example of VRPTW with depot usage constraint -
[from here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrptw_resources).
If I change VehicleNumber on different value(for example from 4 to 6), solution will never be found. This example only works with the specified property values. Why?

I checked C# and Python examples, result is the same.

Comment: General remark (for a very general question; no details given): NP-hard problems are very *unstable* in terms of solvers by nature. While SAT-solvers for example usually solve problems with 100 million variables, theory guarantees us (if assuming P != NP), that there will also be an instance with only 100 variables we can't solve.     This also means, that a tiny change to the instance often can render a problem unsolvable (without us being able to recognize that fact a-priori; also guaranteed by theory). The routing solver is *heavily* heuristic-based.

Comment: How can I use this feature of or-tools if it unstable? In my current project this constraint dropped all

Answer (score 2):

Because the problem is over constrained with 6 vehicles.

This code creates one interval per vehicle. These intervals have a fixed duration and a maximum end time. 4 such intervals fit in the allowed time, 6 do not.

Comment: Why algo can give solution with 4 vehicles, and cann't with 6? It could use 4 out of 6, and keep 2 as unused. How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to create the fixed interval variables as optional. To do this, you need to pass a Boolean variable that indicates if the vehicle is active. You can use solver->MakeIsDifferentCstCt(start_var_of_vehicle_i, index_of_end_route_for_vehicle_i)

Comment: Can I see some example with it for understanding?
I found optional flag for interval, and when I setted to true, breaks stopped working for solution.

Comment: @LaurentPerron,  in MakeIsDifferentCstCt,   what does "CstCt" stands for? Constant constraint? Cast Constraint?

Comment: ConstantConstraint: MakeIsDifferentFromConstantConstraint

Answer (score 0):

This is an optimization problem right. These kind of problems with more constraints will only have 1 solution. At specific constraints, only 1 solution is possible for the problem. If you want the solution for 6 vehicles, change the constraints, variables or any other things which can be changes so that the problem needs a solution only using 6 vehicles. If the problem can be solved using 4 vehicles  it wouldn't use 6 vehicles because that is what optimization is, using as less resources as possible.